# PostgreSQL set field of JSON object in JSON array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
| id (SERIAL) | game (TEXT) | players (JSONB) |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
|      1      | chess       | [{name: Joe, role: admin}, {name: Mike, role: user}] |
|      2      | football    | [{name: Foo, role: user}, {name: Bar, role: user}] |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

I want to set the role of a player (Joe) to a certain value (user) in a certain game (chess), so the result should look like this:

```
| id (SERIAL) | game (TEXT) | players (JSONB) |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
|      1      | chess       | [{name: Joe, role: user}, {name: Mike, role: user}] |
|      2      | football    | [{name: Foo, role: user}, {name: Bar, role: user}] |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Is it possible to achieve this with a single query?

Comment: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Comment: Well I knew this would come... Thanks, but I know you should avoid using JSON in a relational database. My use case is very special and requires JSON, otherwise I wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by recreating the json array on each update.

SQL for table creation and example data insertion:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
  game TEXT,
  players JSONB
);

INSERT INTO test_table(game, players)
    VALUES
      ('chess', '[{"name": "Joe", "role": "admin"}, {"name": "Mike", "role": "user"}]'),
      ('football', '[{"name": "Foo", "role": "user"}, {"name": "Bar", "role": "user"}]');
```

The inserted data:

```
+----+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id |   game   |                               players                                |
+----+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | chess    | [{"name": "Joe", "role": "admin"}, {"name": "Mike", "role": "user"}] |
|  2 | football | [{"name": "Foo", "role": "user"}, {"name": "Bar", "role": "user"}]   |
+----+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Update query:

```
WITH json_rows AS
(SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(players) as json_data FROM test_table
WHERE game = 'chess'),
 updated_rows AS (
    SELECT
      id,
      array_to_json(array_agg(
      CASE WHEN json_data -> 'name' = '"Joe"'
        THEN jsonb_set(json_data, '{role}', '"user"')
      ELSE json_data END)) as updated_json
    FROM json_rows
    GROUP BY id
)
UPDATE test_table SET players = u.updated_json
FROM updated_rows u
WHERE test_table.id = u.id;
```

Results of the query:

```
+----+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id |   game   |                               players                               |
+----+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2 | football | [{"name": "Foo", "role": "user"}, {"name": "Bar", "role": "user"}]  |
|  1 | chess    | [{"name": "Joe", "role": "user"}, {"name": "Mike", "role": "user"}] |
+----+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The query works in the following way:

1. Convert the json array to json rows and filter them by the `game` property. This is done by creating the `json_rows` CTE.
2. Update the json data in the json rows where the user "Joe" is found.
3. Once you have the new json values, just do an update based on the id.

**Note:**  As you can see, in the current implementation the json array gets recreated (only in the rows that need to be updated). This may cause a change in the order of the elements inside the array.