# How to update JSONB array based on property name?

Tags: json, postgresql

I would like to update fields of the following JSON array (stored in a column with JSONB datatype) based on the objectId.

```
        [
            {
                objectId: 'gDKn1jM5d',
                objectType: 'type1',
                posX: 50,
                posY: 100,
            },
            {
                objectId: '4dg5E8BDv',
                objectType: 'type2',
                posX: 50,
                posY: 100,
            },
            {
                objectId: 'ZmCwOf5N2',
                objectType: 'type3',
                posX: 100,
                posY: 150,
            }
        ]
```

In Mongodb I can use a simple update statement but I was not able to find a way in postgres.

For example I would like to update all array elements with objectId 'ZmCwOf5N2' to the posX value 300 (that means it would only affect the 3rd array item).

I'm looking for a plain SQL statement in order to execute the update.
The postgres version is 11.

It is not possible for me to install extensions because I'm using a database as a service provider. However, in case there is no easy way to accomplish the update statement, I would be able to add a postgres function using e.g. C code.

Comment: The clear answer has posted @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype

Comment: I've seen that but it does not describe how to update an array item by property value but instead only by array index.

Comment: You can check my answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55071171/postgresql-set-field-of-json-object-in-json-array/55080030#55080030

Comment: I've seen that too. Do you know if that's the only solution? If so, it means that conditional (based on property) array manipulation is not yet supported I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl t
SET    js = 
   (
   SELECT jsonb_agg(CASE WHEN elem->>'objectId' = 'ZmCwOf5N2'
                         THEN jsonb_set(elem, '{posX}', to_jsonb(int '300'))
                         ELSE elem
                    END) AS  js1 
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(t.js) elem
   )
WHERE  t.js @> '[{"objectId": "ZmCwOf5N2"}]';
```

Note that this ..

- adds the 'posX' key if it's missing
- updates rows even where nothing changes

To only update *existing* keys and only update the row if the update actually changes the value:

```
UPDATE tbl t
SET    js = 
   (
   SELECT jsonb_agg(CASE WHEN elem->>'objectId' = 'ZmCwOf5N2'
                         THEN jsonb_set(elem, '{posX}', to_jsonb(int '300'), false)  -- !
                         ELSE elem
                    END) AS  js1 
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(t.js) elem
   )
WHERE  t.js @> '[{"objectId": "ZmCwOf5N2"}]'
AND    js <>
   (
   SELECT jsonb_agg(CASE WHEN elem->>'objectId' = 'ZmCwOf5N2'
                         THEN jsonb_set(elem, '{posX}', to_jsonb(int '300'), false)
                         ELSE elem
                    END) AS  js1 
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(t.js) elem
   );  --!
```

See:

- [How to update complex jsonb column?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/146730/3684)
- [Update key value in jsonb array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710841/update-key-value-in-jsonb-array-of-objects/50711425#50711425)

Comment: This looks like a very good solution. Thanks a lot! Do you know if a native solution (a solution that is targeted specifically for that use case so it can be done in less code) is planned?

Comment: @microman: This is currently (Postgres 11) the shortest and fastest way. (Also note the variant I added!) Adding parts of the SQL/JSON path language is planned for Postgres 12. Not sure if this will be covered.